# Two geom_bar() and wrong order of factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have problem with correct order of factor variable while ploting bars in ggplot2. I am using two geom_bars with subsets of original dataset (variable g with two levels 'A' and 'B').

How can I preserve original order of factor variable? 
There is no problem when my var is numeric, but let assume that x should be factor.

Here is my code:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

dane<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=seq(-5,4),g=rep(c('A','B'),each=5))
    dane$x<-as.factor(dane$x)

      ggplot(data=dane,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=g)) + 
        geom_bar(subset=.(g=='A'),stat='identity') +
        geom_bar(subset=.(g=='B'),stat='identity')
```

and result

[image: WrongOrder]

**edit:**
I forgot to copy code for libraries.

Comment: It seems worth noting that a simplified version of your example produces the desired output: `ggplot(dane, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`.

Comment: I think the subsetting may be messing up the factor levels. This feels like the wrong behavior to me. It _should_ respect the order of the levels, no matter what. You might try looking on github for an issue related to this.

Comment: @bdemarest It is only an example. I know that I could use only one geom_bar, but in fact some times I need to have more than one.

Comment: what's this `subset=.(g=="A")`. I've never seen this.

Comment: I took this from the examples on the Internet to subset datasets for geom_bars. This is from plyr package.

Comment: FWIW the only place I can find the subset argument documented is in the changelog, which states "subset: experimental new feature.  Layers now have a subset argument, which takes subsets formatted like .(var1 < 5, var2 == 3) etc." My advice is to stay away from undocumented experimental new features.

Comment: @Ista, problem still occurs using `geom_bar(data=dane[dane$g == "A",],stat="identity")` so it's probably not specific to `subset` argument.

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer on github (really fast, I am impressed :)). Brian Diggs proposed to use `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to solve my problem. [**Here's the link to my github report and solution**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/787#issuecomment-15429475). Now, the  result is as I wanted.

```
ggplot(data=dane,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=g)) + 
    geom_bar(subset=.(g=='A'),stat='identity') +
    geom_bar(subset=.(g=='B'),stat='identity') +
    scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I hope other users will find this post useful. ;)